# How change PivotItem Header color for active item / inactive item (in xaml)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

How i can change the active/inactive color of `Pivot->PivotItem->Header`?

demo pickture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush` and `PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush` brushes, more info at https://blog.kulman.sk/changing-the-pivotitem-header-color-in-windows-phone-8-1-xaml/